# Make images inside the circle look circular using d3js

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have a graph with bunch of circles, im adding images inside the circle. Im trying to make the image circular and fit completley inside the circle but its not working. I want the image to look like bubbles.

Here is the code

```
const containerWidth = this.graphWidth;
const containerHeight = this.graphHeight; // You can adjust the aspect ratio as needed

// Set the margins
const margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 70, left: 60 };
const width = containerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = containerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Remove any existing SVG
d3.select(this.container.nativeElement).select("svg").remove();

// Append the SVG object to the existing container
const svg:any = d3.select(this.container.nativeElement)
.append("svg")
.attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
.attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${containerWidth} ${containerHeight}`)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

// Create a scale for the bubble size based on the data values
const sizeScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => +d['value'])])
  .range([10, 50]); // Adjust the range for your desired bubble size range

// Create a force simulation
 const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
  .force("x", d3.forceX(width / 2).strength(0.05))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(height / 2).strength(0.05))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(d => sizeScale(d['value']) + 2))
  .stop();

// Run the simulation for a fixed number of iterations
 for (let i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
  simulation.tick();
 }

//Create the bubbles, ensuring they stay within the SVG boundaries
svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", d => Math.max(sizeScale(d.value), Math.min(width - sizeScale(d.value), d.x)))
  .attr("cy", d => Math.max(sizeScale(d.value), Math.min(height - sizeScale(d.value), d.y)))
  .attr("r", d => sizeScale(d.value))
  .attr("fill", "blue");

//Create the bubbles with images
svg.selectAll("image")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("image")
.attr("xlink:href", d => d.img) // Set the image URL
.attr("x", d => d.x - sizeScale(d.value))
.attr("y", d => d.y - sizeScale(d.value))
.attr("width", d => sizeScale(d.value) * 2)
.attr("height", d => sizeScale(d.value) * 2)
.style("border-radius", d => `${sizeScale(d.value)}px`);
```

Here is the image.
[image]

i want the image to look circular and take the height and width of the blue bubble